# Spring data hierarchical query causes N + 1

Tags: spring-data

[Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd4WX.png)

As part of re-writing a legacy I have come across the above data model that we want to model using Spring Data JPA. 
The section entity contains subsections stored in the same table with a parent child relation
Each section contains many questions
Each question contains many profiles.
With the below code in spring data I encounter N + 1 issue.
There was a question in the past for a similar issue ([JPA/Hibernate load recursive object graph without N+1/cartesian products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341533/jpa-hibernate-load-recursive-object-graph-without-n1-cartesian-products))
I would like to know if there are new and better ways to solve this N+1 issue?